# IntelliJ IDE gives error when using Try-Catch with Resources

Tags: java, intellij-idea, try-catch, try-catch-finally, try-with-resources

I am attempting to use JDK 7's "try-catch with resources" statement; IntelliJ highlights  my resource line, saying

> Try-with-resources are not supported at this language level.

When I try to compile, I get:

> java: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.6
>    (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)

I checked that try-with-resources is enabled for my current project, and that my project is using JDK 7 (Library:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11).  Any ideas?  I can't figure out what option to change (if that's even the issue).

Comment: look in file -> protect structure (or ctrl-alt-shift s) that both the jdk as well as the language level are set to 7

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Click on the File menu, open Project Structure, then under "Settings" there should be "Project". Within that tab, there'll be an SDK Settings option which specifies the language version you want to use.

See the [JetBrains help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/project-page.html) for more details ("Project language level").

Answer (score 52):

The only way this error will occur is if your module's language level isn't set to 1.7+. This needs to be set in either your IntelliJ project/module settings, the project's `pom.xml` file, or both.

**IntelliJ**

[image]

**Maven**

```xml
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

Module settings can override project settings; if setting this at the project level and you have a specific issue in a module, check the module settings as well.

Comment: This is no longer valid in AS 0.3.4 and above.

Comment: @Adam Android Studio?  The one based on the Intellij beta? What specifically isn't valid? Wouldn't it make more sense to provide actionable information, although nobody was talking about Android development?

Comment: This was the reason I had this issue.

Comment: I still had to make changes in the "Modules" tab, it can overwrite Language level from the "Project" tab. So if the problem remains, check the Language level settings in "Modules" tab.

Comment: @chris544 That's a good point; I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: Ty for mentioning Maven...I was checking in my Intellij configurations and everything seemed ok

Comment: If you are using Gradle check sourceCompatibility is set to 1.7 +

Answer (score 11):

Besides mentioned instructions I also had to specify language level per module as well.   File -> Project Structure -> Modules

Comment: Thanks I had to do it too, you're a lifesaver

Answer (score 8):

Also check your code. You might have accidentally did something like this:

```
try (HttpClients.createMinimal().execute(new HttpGet(String.format(
          "http://127.0.0.1:%s/extra/LifecycleServlet?action=shutdown",
          runningPort)))) {
```

instead of

```
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = HttpClients.createMinimal().execute(new HttpGet(String.format(
          "http://127.0.0.1:%s/extra/LifecycleServlet?action=shutdown",
          runningPort)))) {
```

easy mistake to make when you don't intend on using the result of your closeable resource. yet it will have that misleading error.

Answer (score 3):

Pictorial representation of module settings. 
[image]