# How can I write ByteArrayOutput stream to a file in groovy?

Tags: groovy, fileoutputstream, try-with-resources, bytearrayoutputstream

In Java, I can easily use following code, to write a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to a file. However, `try-with-resources` doesn't work in Groovy :(

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = getByteStreamMethod();
try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("thefilename")) {
    byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(outputStream);
}
```

I have been trying to follow links like http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/groovy-goodness-readers-and-writers.html
and
SO answer here [IntelliJ error - java: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.6 error. Even though in project settings 1.7 JDK is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100806/intellij-error-java-try-with-resources-is-not-supported-in-source-1-6-error)

but I am not able to think of Groovy syntax, to write above java code block as. 
Could you please do a little handholding here as to how to write above java code block in Groovy?

PS: I am using Groovy **v2.4.12**

Answer (score 5):

Groovy's alternatives for [try-with-resources](/questions/tagged/try-with-resources) are methods like:

- `.withClosable(Closure cl)`
- `.withOutputStream(Closure cl)`

In your case following example would write data from `ByteArrayOutputStream` to a given `File`:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
os.withCloseable {
    it << "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet".bytes
}

new File("/tmp/lorem.txt").withOutputStream { stream ->
    os.writeTo(stream)
}

println new File("/tmp/lorem.txt").text
```

In the last line we are printing current content of `/tmp/lorem.txt` file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

in groovy for in/out streams there is an extension method [withStream(Closure)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/OutputStream.html#withStream(groovy.lang.Closure)) :

Passes this Stream to the closure, ensuring that the stream is closed after the closure returns, regardless of errors.

So, your java code could look like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = getByteStreamMethod();
new FileOutputStream("thefilename").withStream{outputStream->
    byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(outputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
void saveToFile(ByteArrayOutputStream os, File output) {
    output.bytes = os.toByteArray()
}
```

Although I guess that it is not the best way when handling large size files as the stream will first be converted into bytes before saving.