# PMML to Java or JPMML

Tags: java, arrays, pmml

Was working on a conversion of a PMML via .CSV file to Java format and the errors given are as follows:

- Try-with-resources are not supported at language level '5'
- java: try-with-resource is not supported in -source 1.5
- java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5

looking it up and there are no results regarding those errors. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and everything seems to be complete as in other projects, it's working properly. May I know the solution on this or on how to resolve this?

Comment: I had a look at SO, and I've found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100806/intellij-error-java-try-with-resources-is-not-supported-in-source-1-6-error does this help you out?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. It helped a lot!