# Intellij picking up JDK 1.6 instead of 1.8

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I download project from Repo today and try to run it for the first time and it wont Pick JDK 1.8 installed. Before you downvote stating this is Repeated question I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460026/intellij-ide-gives-error-when-using-try-catch-with-resources) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100806/intellij-error-java-try-with-resources-is-not-supported-in-source-1-6-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747254/getting-compile-error-for-diamond-operator-in-idea-ide) . I have checked everywhere on the internet but to No avail. And If Downvotiong, give explicit/very very solid reason for the same.

Here is the error message :-

```
error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
                                         ^
```

Im using Mac and Intellij Ultimate. Here is my `java --version`

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Here is my File > Project Structure > Modules >Sources

```
8. Lambdas, type annotations etc.
```

File > Project Structure > Project >Project SDK > `javaversion "1.8.0_25"`

Project language level > `SDK Default(8 - Lambdas, type annotation etc.)`

In my /bash_profile is have `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_25)`

Comment: Also if upvoting please mention reason for the same as well so that I keep that in mind very specifically

Comment: What do you get when you go to Project Structure > Modules > (pick your module) > Dependencies > Module SDK?

Comment: @rgettman I see 1.8(java version 1.8.0_25") in the module SDK. Apply> Restart>Run: 'Grails:<project name > . Same error

Answer (score 1):

Ok So after brainstorming (Lets call it in the most R-rated strong language  usage brainstorming) I found that the BuildConfig file has got

```
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
```

Changed that to 1.7 and the problem of not identifying the <> is gone. There are other problems but they are for some other day.